# is there something am i missing, code doesnt work on 1/3 of data, on 2/3 it work correctly?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-analysis

I have a problem.

I have data, with ~40 columns, column 6 & 10 are integers by default, which code as follows works on 2/3 of data but doesn't work on other 1/3 of it, I have no idea why:

```
data = pd.read_csv(path,sep='|',header=None,index_col=0,dtype='str')
data[10] = pd.to_numeric(data[10])
data[6] = pd.to_numeric(data[6])
data['pom_sucet'] = data.groupby([1,2,3,4,5,17,18,22,25])[10].transform(sum)
data['pom_pocet'] = data.groupby([1,2,3,4,5,17,18,22,25])[6].transform(sum)

data = data.drop_duplicates([1,2,3,4,5,17,18,22,25])
#print (data)
data[10] = data['pom_sucet'].drop(columns=['pom_sucet'])
```

In case it doesn't sum the integers it get NaN , and transform my column from int to object, which cause lot of trouble.

It doesn't seem to have pattern. Other columns are normal, what should be the case?

Comment: i tried to simplify it for me to understand it better

Comment: It's *very* difficult to say what's going wrong without an example that fully reproduces the problem. The only guidance I can give is that because the `pd.to_numeric` passes without errors columns `10` and `6` are guaranteed to be numeric, so their transform sum will also be numeric. However because you're reading in data and then just going for it, my guess is that `[1,2,3,4,5,17,18,22,25]` have a few `null` values. If any grouping key is `null` transform will output `NaN` for that row. Though, I can't understand how you'd get an object column for the result.

Comment: hello, im summing only column 6 and 10 so when  one of grouped is NaN it shouldnt be affected at sum, column 6 and 10 are good at initial data mean there are integers to sum, i will test your suggest, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ALollz, you were right, in some rows i had NaN value, when i removed it it works fine.

> It's very difficult to say what's going wrong without an example that fully reproduces the problem. The only guidance I can give is that because the pd.to_numeric passes without errors columns 10 and 6 are guaranteed to be numeric, so their transform sum will also be numeric. However because you're reading in data and then just going for it, my guess is that [1,2,3,4,5,17,18,22,25] have a few null values. If any grouping key is null transform will output NaN for that row. Though, I can't understand how you'd get an object column for the result.

thank you, i couldn't see this yesterday (maybe i was just too tired to see)